# figures, (gray Filter ) to hide a part of a figure

Tags: graphics, floats

I have this chart I would the black framed part to be hidden with a gray filter (and just this part). Is there any way to do this?

Here is the figure [image: gray filter on figures..]

-- While I am using LaTeX, I would be OK with any other way if there is no way to do it on LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way with tikz package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{FigureForTikz.png}};
   \draw [fill=gray,xshift=1.35cm] (-2.95,-3.75)--(6.8,-3.75)--(6.8,3.7)--(-2.95,3.7)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

the result is this:

[image: not perfect image]

Edit:
with opacity and better numbers (as in my first comment)
[image: with opacity]

Comment: the advantage of this method is that you can add opacity=0.97 (for example) in the options of the rectangle and you will have an almost hidden part.

The disadvantage is that you have to "play around" with the numbers until find the numbers you want

Comment: excuse me ( yeah it does matter the choice of numbers... particulalrly that am peretty new on latex ) by the way can it be as clear as possible means ( as when we do a screen shot , I would  like the hidden part to still readable .. but just a filter on a part of it ) is there any way to do it but easier? ( I appreciate your feedback :) )

Comment: Sorry, but I can not imagine a really simpler way for this.... I can just give you the simpler command for the rectangle that is \draw[fill=gray, opacity=0.3] (<x1>,<y1>)rectangle(<x2>,<y2>);
The x1,y1 is the one point and the x2,y2 the point at the opposite corner of the first... This is the simpler way I can imagine... You have to give two points to select the area....

Comment: You are welcome ;) keep in touch with the subject... may be some time someone will give you beter solution (like inkscape program... but I haven't try)